# Data issue or is there an issue in my observations?

Tags: futures

I am using 1 sec snapshot data to backtest on 2019 data collected by me. It has both bid and ask.

I purchased 4 years data for the same instrument, sadly this data doesn't have bid-ask. When I run the backtest on 2018 and 2019(I purchased another set to be sure), the results are more or less inline with expectations.

Number of trades generated: 332, 517 respectively.

However 2016 and 2017, are giving small negative returns for the year which as per my original thesis should not happen. I investigated and here are my thoughts:

1- The market turnover on the instruments in question was a half of what it is today.

2- The average daily movement on the instrument has increased quite a lot on the instrument, which is a factor in my strategy.

I have used the strategy live and it seems to work. Just test trades as of now.

I am wondering whether to put the concern regarding 2016, 2017 returns on the side(Investigate them more and more but not throw the strategy away) or back to the drawing board.

How significant should I consider the returns of 4 and 3 years ago compared to last two years?

Comment: Hi: how are you backtesting 2016 and 2017 if you don't have the data ?

Comment: This could be (hard to say definitively) a potential hint of a model that is over-fitted to 2019 conditions, if it fails out of sample in other years. Difficult to say not knowing the instruments in question, but 2019 had a constant theme of central bank reflation and super-low FX vol that might well influence your results thus

Comment: @demully the instrument in question was very volatile in 2019 and pretty stable in 2018. Both years performing quite well. In 2019, I used 6 months as in-sample and the rest as out sample. Overfitting or survivor bias might still be present, can always be present.

Comment: @markleeds I have the price data but not price-bid-ask.

Comment: that shouldn't make much of a difference so I'm honestly at a loss for reasons.

Comment: Just because a strategy works now doesn't mean it would work always (either in the past or in the future). Why do you say it should not lose money in 2016 and 2017?